# Joomla 2.5 angular ajax post doesn't working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

I'm making a joomla 2.5 component and i have a problem with a angular post request.

Here's my Javascript (angular framework):

```
var itemToSend = "ok";

$http.post('http://mediastore.dev/index.php?option=com_mediastore&task=sendMail&format=raw', itemToSend)
     .success(function(data) {
         console.log("my->"+data);
     })
     .error(function() {
         console.log('shit happens');
     });
```

And my controller:

```
public function sendMail() {
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        $res = $_POST['itemToSend'];
        echo $res;
    }else {
        echo 'nothing';
    }
}
```

And the callback return 
my->
**Notice**:  Undefined index: itemToSend

Why Undefined index ? What's wrong ?

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

---

I've tried this before, but it was the same issue..

I've change my php to this:

```
public function sendMail() {
     if(isset($_POST['itemToSend'])) {
         $res = $_POST['itemToSend'];
         echo $res;
     }else {
         echo 'nothing';
     }
}
```

and my js:

```
var itemToSend = {
    itemToSend: "ok"
};

$http.post('http://mediastore.dev/index.php?option=com_mediastore&task=sendMail&format=raw', itemToSend)
    .success(function(data) {
         console.log("my->"+data);
    })
```

And it always return "nothing"

Comment: one you should check `isset($_POST['itemToSend'])` as `$_POST` is always set, second you are not defining a post variable named itemToSend

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` with Joomla. Check the documentation on how to retrieve inputs using JInput: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Answer (score 1):

I don't undertand why but.. it seems it was the angular $http request.

the angular version doesn't work:

```
$http.post('index.php?option=com_mediastore&task=sendMail&format=raw', itemToSend)
     .success(function(data) {
         console.log("my->"+data);
     })
```

but the jquery version works:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?option=com_mediastore&task=sendMail&format=raw",
    data: itemToSend,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

**I would be interested to know why ??**

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't send data through FormData, but from payload instead.

Through PHP, you can't use $_POST or Joomla's post input method to retrieve this data, you have to do this:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

... and treat the $post variable as if it is an object.